# Count occurances with if statement python

Tags: python

Think of the `Unit Circle x 2`. What I have done is create two lists, one for `x` and one for `y`, producing 500 pairs of random (x,y).   Then I created `r=x2+y2` in my `while` loop, where `r` is the radius and `x2=x**2 and y2=y**2`.  What I want to be able to do is count the number of times `r=<2.` I assume my `if` statement needs to be in the `while` loop, but I don't know how to actually count the number of times the condition `r=<2`is met. Do I need to create a `list` for the `r` values?

```
import random
from math import *

def randomgen(N):
    rlg1=[]
    rlg2=[]
    a=random.randint(0,N)
    b=float(a)/N
    return b

i=0
rlg=[]
rlg2=[]
countlist=[]
while i<500:
    x=randomgen(100)*2
    y=randomgen(100)*2
    x2=x**2
    y2=y**2
    r=x2+y2
    rlg.append(x)
    rlg2.append(y)
    print rlg[i],rlg2[i]
    i+=1

    if r<=2:
```

Comment: If you just want to count when the condition is met, why not have a counter variable, initialized to zero before the loop, and then incremented each time `if r<=2` is true?

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
from math import *

def randomgen(N):
    rlg1=[]
    rlg2=[]
    a=random.randint(0,N)
    b=float(a)/N
    return b

i=0
rlg=[]
rlg2=[]
countlist=[]
amount = 0
while i<500:
    x=randomgen(100)*2
    y=randomgen(100)*2
    x2=x**2
    y2=y**2
    r=x2+y2
    rlg.append(x)
    rlg2.append(y)
    print rlg[i],rlg2[i]
    i+=1

    if r<=2:
        amount += 1
```

Comment: Can you please explain your solutions rather than just providing code? Thanks.

Comment: The solution is meant to produce the number of times the random pair would fit inside the circle of radius 2.

Answer (score 0):

You need *two* counters here. One for the total number of points (`i`) and one for the number of points that lie within your circle `r <= 2` (I'm calling this one `isInside`). You only want to increment the `isInside` counter if the point lies within your circle (`r <= 2`).

```
i = 0
rlg = []
rlg2 = []
countlist = []

isInside = 0

while i < 500:

    x=randomgen(100)*2
    y=randomgen(100)*2
    x2=x**2
    y2=y**2
    r=x2+y2
    rlg.append(x)
    rlg2.append(y)
    print rlg[i],rlg2[i]
    i+=1

    if r <= 2:
        # increment your isInside counter
        isInside += 1
```